# How can I make these divs inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant seem to make the elements inside this div inline.
Id like the h3 to be above the form then the next h3 and form beside that.

```html
<div class="title">

  <h3><b>Click To Encounter A Pokemon</b></h3>
  <form method="post" action="/encounter">
    <button style="background-color: Transparent;" onclick="catchPokemon()">
                            <img type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zs02wMs.png" alt="Catch Pokemon" width="100"
                                height="100">
                        </button>
  </form>

  <h3><b>Click To Catch Pokemon</b></h3>
  <form method="post" action="/encounter">
    <button style="background-color: Transparent;" onclick="catchPokemon()">
                            <img type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zs02wMs.png" alt="Catch Pokemon" width="100"
                                height="100">
                        </button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Post CSS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* add a container flexbox that acts as 'row' then within that the forms which are themselves also flexboxes, but 'columns'.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
button {
    line-height: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

    <form class="column" method="post" action="/encounter">
        <h3>Click To Encounter A Pokemon</h3>
        <button onclick="catchPokemon()">
            <img type="image" src="https://picsum.photos/100?v=1">
        </button>
    </form>
    
    <form class="column" method="post" action="/encounter">
        <h3>Click To Catch Pokemon</h3>
        <button onclick="catchPokemon()">
            <img type="image" src="https://picsum.photos/100?v=2">
        </button>
    </form>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="title" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <div>
    <h3><b>Click To Encounter A Pokemon</b></h3>
    <form method="post" action="/encounter">
      <button style="background-color: Transparent;" onclick="catchPokemon()">
           <img type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zs02wMs.png" alt="Catch Pokemon" width="100" height="100">
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3><b>Click To Catch Pokemon</b></h3>
    <form method="post" action="/encounter">
      <button style="background-color: Transparent;" onclick="catchPokemon()">
         <img type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zs02wMs.png" alt="Catch Pokemon" width="100" height="100">
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a solution if you really don't want to add external styling (a css file linked to your html file).
You can add div containers around the content you want aligned, and then, use `display: flex;` to the `.title` div, as shown above. Using `display: inline;` on the new div containers could also work, but you probably will need to adjust the margin to your liking.

Comment: Thanks! Im definatly happy with the result.
I did "text-align: center; for my title and it centered the button and text too.
Also changed "justify-content: center" which gives me the buttons centered.
Then i added a margin to my secondary divs to space them.
Thanks for helping jump start my brain :P

Comment: @Turtle if you're happy with the result you could consider up-voting and/or marking as the chosen answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display those div's in line you can use css styles. Most Popular is just typing `float: left;` but I prefer to use flexbox. It's less complicated.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

But in this example you can use Float Left/Float right:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vixK.png)

You have to add this to your css code. If you don't want to use styles from another file you can add it in `<style>` tag.

For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1Du.png)

You put this in the `<head>` tag.

It should look like that. If you wanted this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNPOV.png)

You don't need to put image in form when you wanna make a hyperlink. Use an `<a>` tag.

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Good luck in programming :)

Comment: You should include the actual CSS rather than images of it in your answer

Comment: I didn't down-vote you BTW

Comment: So I need on my "container" just flex-direction: row. So default all the divs inside go left to right? How do I center it. To be honest I'm getting quite confused wrapping my head around this simple thing for some reason and I'm sure I've done it before and can't lol

Comment: I exactly want the second last image you have. But those buttons  centered. And I'll likely wanna add more down the line. The reply I guess I'm looking for is what should I group in a div tag and what exactly should I put for the css. Thanks

Comment: `But in this example you can use Float Left/Float right.` Since `flex` and `grid` is widely supported you should use `float` only if you really want text to float around e.g. an image, but not for other layout purposes.